# Is it OK to start a bounty on a partially answered question to get more information?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Two days ago [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912581/what-does-mediaplayer-info-warning-973-0-mean?noredirect=1#comment44226225_27912581) . I got a pretty good suggestion (this doesn't actually solve the problem). It's kind of weird, but there is no reference in the documentation. I found [a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705792/mediaplayer-oninfolistener-info-warning-973-0) which is unsolved.

Here are my questions:

- Is it worth it to start a bounty to get more attention?
- If I let go and try something else, what should I do with the question (close it, etc.)?

Comment: In brief -- yes, it is fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Posting a bounty to a question that is answered, but not with as much detail, depth, quality, etc. in order to attract better answers is one of the primary reasons that the bounty system is in place.

So yes, you can bounty a question to encourage even higher quality answers than what is there.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely.

Sometimes a question is not answered or only partially answered because of the following:

- It does not attract enough attention from the people with the appropriate expertise
- The potential reward for answering is not sufficient to entice people to put in the effort to give a comprehensive answer

The bounty system gives you the opportunity to both gain greater exposure and incentivize others to give better answers.  It does not matter who asked the original question - the offer of a bounty is a valuable contribution to the community.